# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in left outer join with table values function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, table-valued-parameters

I write this code

```
SELECT tblprsn.prsnid, tblprsn.name 
FROM tblprsn LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             (
                SELECT tblrtm.rtmid 
                FROM dbo.getrtmn(tblprsn.prsnid) as getrtmn_1
             ) AS tblgetrtmn 
             ON tblprsn.prsnid = tblgetrtmn.rtmid
```

the dbo.getrtmn is a table-value function and have a uniqueidentifier field named rtmid.
prsnid is uniqueidentifier

When I run this SQL query cause error:

> The multi-part identifier " tblprsn.prsnid" could not be bound.

Answer (score 6):

This is your query:

```
SELECT tblprsn.prsnid, tblprsn.name 
FROM tblprsn LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT tblrtm.rtmid 
      FROM dbo.getrtmn(tblprsn.prsnid) as getrtmn_1
     ) AS tblgetrtmn 
     ON tblprsn.prsnid = tblgetrtmn.rtmid
```

You are referencing the first table in the subquery.  This isn't allowed.  First, I don't think the subquery is necessary.  You are only selecting from the first table and doing a `left outer join` to keep all the records.  The only affect of the subquery would be to multiply the rows.  So, as you have written it, this query should do pretty much the same thing (except for duplicates):

```
SELECT tblprsn.prsnid, tblprsn.name 
FROM tblprsn;
```

You can do what you want in the original query, though, using `apply` rather than `join`:

```
SELECT tblprsn.prsnid, tblprsn.name 
FROM tblprsn cross apply 
     dbo.getrtmn(tblprsn.prsnid) tblgetrtmn 
where tblprsn.prsnid = tblgetrtmn.rtmid
```

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko . . . There shouldn't have been a subquery around the function call.

Comment: different semantics of queries with OUTER APPLY + subquery and CROSS APPLY + WHERE clause http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f718/5

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko . . . I realize that.  The original query is probably not the real query the OP needs to work on.  If so, the much simplified version of just selecting from the table would probably work.  Your SQLFiddle does a good job of showing the difference (which is the same as the difference between an outer join and inner join).

Answer (score 1):

instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN use OUTER APPLY with correleted subquery. The OUTER APPLY clause return all the rows on the left side table whether they return any rows in the table -valued-function or not, and thus similar to LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT t.prsnid, t.name, getrtmn_1.*
FROM tblprsn t OUTER APPLY (
                            SELECT rtmid 
                            FROM dbo.getrtmn(t.prsnid) AS tblgetrtmn
                            WHERE t.prsnid = tblgetrtmn.rtmid  
                            ) as getrtmn_1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f718/1)